# How to turn off USB/Ethernet/HDMI/LEDs on Google Coral Dev Board

Tags: google-coral

I'd like to reduce idle power consumption on the Google Coral Dev Board anyway I can by turning off USB/ethernet/HDMI/LEDs etc. I'm struggling to find much information for how to do this. I've searched through i.MX8M documentation, and have tried similar approaches like you would do with a Raspberry Pi but obviously these aren't the same and I've struggled to find corresponding locations in /sys/.

Can anyone recommend documentation or give advice on how to turn off these components from the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if those parts can be turn off, but if power is what concerns you, you can try turning on this option:

```
CONFIG_IMX8MQ_PHANBELL_POWERSAVE
```

in the kernel's defconfig.
You can follow [this answer](https://github.com/f0cal/google-coral/issues/56#issuecomment-632120325) to see how that is done :)